# Lost power now my hostname will not resolve

Tags: debian, hostname

I have a Debian file server I'm accessing from windows clients.  Until a power outage a few days ago I had no issues accessing via hostname.  Now I must use the ip handed out by my router.  I can ssh (putty) into it via hostname, but cannot ping or access my samba shares with hostname.  I have rebooted my router, restarted server and client machines.  What gives?

Seems that the server still knows it's hostname - just isn't resolving in some places.

```
tone@homeserver:~$ hostname
homeserver
tone@homeserver:~$
```

edit: my router (linksys running dd-wrt) tells me that all my other machines have a hostname mapped, so i strongly suspect the issue is something in the configuration of this particular machine.  I also found that the hostname is not resolving anywhere (which is different from my initial statement).

```
DHCP Clients
Host Name   IP Address  MAC Address     Client Lease Time
Zachs-iPod  192.168.1.116   xx:xx:xx:xx:34:2A   1 day 00:00:00
*   192.168.1.109   xx:xx:xx:xx:A8:A8   1 day 00:00:00
Andrea-PC   192.168.1.118   xx:xx:xx:xx:4D:B3   1 day 00:00:00
tsoutherlandpc  192.168.1.145   xx:xx:xx:xx:0A:34   1 day 00:00:00
Tones-iPhone    192.168.1.139   xx:xx:xx:xx:3D:D4   1 day 00:00:00
```

Comment: There's some piecemeal information here. What did you use before for resolution? WINS? A DNS server? Your router handed it out?

Comment: Are all the systems having trouble resolving hostnames or just a few systems?

Comment: You said you can SSH into (a system) by hostname, but that same system can't ping by hostname to the same system? Does it resolve but not ping?

Comment: From the information you have given without the edit, I'd suspect that something was damaged int he router (what kind of router is it?). Inexpensive routers can do *weird* stuff when they fail. But without knowing how you had resolution set up or how each system involved is or isn't resolving, there's not much I could offer on troubleshooting. You could consider setting static IP's and a DNS server on your Debian system and use that...

Comment: my router hands out ips, all systems are having trouble resolving, i can ssh using PuTTY - maybe that program stores the dns??  pings do not work, will not resolve when accessing share i.e. \\homeserver\mediashare.  it's a Linksys WRT54G - only 6 months old.  I flashed with DD-WRT when I got it and have not had any issues yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working now.  after a few reboots both on the server and the router.  setting the ip as static and changing back to dynamic in the router it started working again.  go figure.